# How to get data from JSON string?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
    "response":[2,
        {
            "id":"187",
            "name":"John",
            "surname":"Corner"
        },
        {
            "id":"254",
            "name":"Bob",
            "surname":"Marley"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I parse it using GSON lib in Java?
I tried:

```
static class SearchRequest {
    private Names[] response;

    static class Names {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String surname;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't works :(

Comment: Do you see exceptions due to your JSON string, I modified it and the program worked correctly. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`response` array contains not only `Names`, it also contains an integer value: `response[0]=2`.
So you must use something like

```
private Object[] response;
```

**ADD:**
I think, you have no need to change your JSON, because your `response` is private, so you should use getters:

```
static class SearchRequest {
    private Object[] response;

    static class Names {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String surname;
    }

    public List<Names> getNames() {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(response));
        return (List<Names>) list.subList(1, response.length);
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return (Integer) response[0];
    }

    public void setNames(List<Names> names) {
        response = new Object[names.size() + 1];
        response[0] = names.size();
        for (int i = 0, namesSize = names.size(); i < namesSize; i++) {
            response[i + 1] = names.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! Yeah! Thank you very much. You are right, but Object[] response is not easy solution...I will try to edit JSON string and parse it without integer element.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand you. In method getNames you changed a type of Object from 1 till end of Array to Names.

Comment: I don't know why but my compiler told me that it can not cast from List<Object> to List<Names>

Comment: @user1203901 Sorry, I fix it. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a sample code for testing your case, used `gson-2.1.jar` as library and run it correctly. I modified your JSON string by removing `"2,"` from the beginning of *response* array since it caused exceptions. Take a look at and test this code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Test
{
    static class SearchRequest
    {
        private Names [] response;

        static class Names
        {
            private int id;
            private String name;
            private String surname;
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String str = "{ \"response\":" 
                   + "[{\"id\":\"187\",\"name\":\"John\",\"surname\":\"Corner\"},"
                   + "{\"id\":\"254\",\"name\":\"Bob\",\"surname\":\"Marley\"}]}";

        SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request = gson.fromJson( str, SearchRequest.class );
        System.out.println( "name of 1st: " + request.response [ 0 ].name );
        System.out.println( "surname of 2nd: " + request.response [ 1 ].surname );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
name of 1st: John
surname of 2nd: Marley
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I did the same ^_^. It's easier then use Object[] :)